# Почему цикл не выводит названия файлов? Bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash, циклы

Я сделал цикл, который выводил бы файлы в заданной директории. Скрипт:

```
# !/bin/bash
for file in /Desktop/*
do 
    echo $file
done
```

Но вместо этого он просто выводит /Desktop/* в консоль. Если поменять директорию, то будет просто выводить путь к директории. Как будто в $file хранится аргумент после in. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Меня смущает лишний пробел в первой строке

Comment: А второе что меня смущает — это что обычно папки /Desktop не бывает. Наверное вы хотели $HOME/Desktop

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я использую Ubuntu 14 там Desktop. По крайней мере пишется cd Destop/directory/

Comment: @AlexeyTen действительно, $HOME помог. Странно, что он используется только в bash. Благодарю

Comment: осознайте наконец разницу между [абсолютным и относительным путём](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Путь_к_файлу)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я прекрасно знаю, что такое абсолютный и относительный путь) Просто я не думал, что нужно использовать абсолютный

Comment: а зачем же тогда использовали именно абсолютный `/Desktop`?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin потому что я плохо владею линуксом и не знал, что указание ведущего слеша - это корень

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Кроме того раз нужен абсолютный путь, то нужно еще и пользователя указать: /home/user/Desktop/blabla, я считал, что достаточно /Desktop/blabla и считал это относительным путем

Answer (score -1):

вообще то обычно я делаю так

```
list=`ls /Desktop/*`

for VAL in $list
do
    
echo "$VAL"

done
```

Comment: согласно тексту вопроса. А так можно добавить тильду, для домашнего каталога. В чем вопрос?